# magento 1.9 connect creditmemo id and invoice id

Tags: php, mysql, magento, invoice, mage

I have a bit of a problem right now.

I need to somehow connect the creditmemo id to the invoice id.

If there is an invoice with the id 24.333.001 and I need to do a refund, the creditmemo id should be the next higher invoice id like 24.333.002 (or whatever the latest id is atm).

I know it makes not much sense to skip id's in the database, but it's an explicit wish of a customer.

I tried to check all "creditmemo_id"s in the code, but did't find a solution to my problem.

Anybody out there for a challange? ;)

Thanks

Comment: The question is not very clear. I'd suggest at least to describe the involved DB tables. (also please fix the typo in the title)

Comment: Well it's less the problem which DB-Tables (which I actually don't know at this point), but in which File the creditmemo gets the next possible id and uses it.